# Motion Event Implementation: Can't detect another sequential touch

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, mobile, composable

This is my Thumb Wrestling Game:

I have four states for my game: 00, 01, 10,11

00 if none is pressed.
10 if left is pressed but right is not.
01 if right is pressed but left is not.
11 if both are pressed and call the take damage function.

My problem is that:

Why does my state won't go to 11[image]
How to fix this? Please help me.

```
var touchState by remember { mutableStateOf("00") } // "00", "10", "01", "11"
var firstTouch by remember { mutableStateOf("") } // "", "P1", "P2"



   // Assuming this is the "STATE OF THE HAND BY DRAWABLES" Row
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Gray)
                .weight(1.4f) // Adjust the weight as needed
        ) {
            // Player 1 control area
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(Color.DarkGray)
                    .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->
                        when (motionEvent.action) {
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                                if (touchState == "00") {
                                    touchState = "10"
                                }

                                if (touchState == "01") {
                                    touchState = "11"
                                    //CALL DAMAGE FUNCTION
                                    Log.d("damage", "damage applied to player 2")
                                }


                                if (firstTouch == "") firstTouch = "P1"
                                Log.d("test",touchState)
                            }

                            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {


                                if (touchState == "10") {
                                    touchState = "00"
                                }

                                if (firstTouch == "P1") {
                                    firstTouch = ""
                                }
                                Log.d("test",touchState)
                            }

                        }
                        true
                    }
            )

            // Player 2 control area
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->
                        when (motionEvent.action) {
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {



                                if (touchState == "00") {
                                    touchState = "01"
                                }

                                if (touchState == "10") {
                                    touchState = "11"
                                    //CALL DAMAGE FUNCTION
                                    Log.d("damage", "damage applied to player 1")
                                }

                                if (firstTouch == "") firstTouch = "P2"

                                Log.d("test",touchState)
                            }

                            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                Log.d("test",touchState)


                                if (touchState == "01") {
                                    touchState = "00"
                                }

                                if (firstTouch == "P2") {
                                    firstTouch = ""
                                }

                                Log.d("test",touchState)
                            }
                        }
                        true
                    }
            )

        }
        // Debug Text - Displaying the current touch state and first touch
        Text("Touch State: $touchState, First Touch: $firstTouch")
    }
```